# Jenkins Plugin How to get Job information

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to make a Jenkins plugin. How do you get job information from the plugin? I know

```
public String getShortName(Job job) { ... }
```

However I do not know how to call this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the below groovy script to get all the build numbers from a job.

```
    import hudson.model.*

  BUILD_JOB_NAME = "${BUILD_JOB_NAME}"

def getJobs() {
    def hi = Hudson.instance
    return hi.getItems(Job)
}

def getBuildJob() {
    def buildJob = null
    def jobs = getJobs()
    (jobs).each { job ->
        if (job.displayName == BUILD_JOB_NAME) {
            buildJob = job
        }
    }
    return buildJob
}

def getAllBuildNumbers(Job job) {
    def buildNumbers = []
    (job.getBuilds()).each { build ->
        buildNumbers.add(build.number)
    }
    return buildNumbers
}

def buildJob = getBuildJob()
return getAllBuildNumbers(buildJob)
```

The [Job](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Job.html) jenkins API can give you additional handles to get information about Jobs