# Get Jenkins build number via Groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins parameterized build called "deploy-job", and I use the Extensible Choice option set to System Groovy Choice Parameter. In the Groovy Script box, I have this

```
import hudson.model.*

BUILD_JOB_NAME = "build-multi-branch-pipeline-job"

def getJobs() {
    def hi = Hudson.instance
    return hi.getItems(Job)
}

def getBuildJob() {
    def buildJob = null
    def jobs = getJobs()
    (jobs).each { job ->
        if (job.displayName == BUILD_JOB_NAME) {
            buildJob = job
        }
    }
    return buildJob
}

def getAllBuildNumbers(Job job) {
    def buildNumbers = []
    (job.getBuilds()).each { build ->
        def status = build.getBuildStatusSummary().message
        if (status.contains("stable") || status.contains("normal")) {
          buildNumbers.add(build.BUILD_NUMBER.toString())
        }
    }
    return buildNumbers
}

def buildJob = getBuildJob()
return getAllBuildNumbers(buildJob)
```

However, when I run my "deploy-job", I'm NOT seeing the build numbers of "multi-branch-pipeline-job" in the choice box when I run Build with parameters, it's jub blank!

I suspect I'm not doing this call right?

```
buildNumbers.add(build.BUILD_NUMBER.toString())
```

What is the correct syntax in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ use try-catch to see an error in your choice. this will help you to understand the error.

```
def getAllBuildNumbers(Job job) {
    try {
        ...
        return buildNumbers
    }catch(Throwable t){ 
        return [t.toString()]
    }
}
```

2/ your answer is already there

[Jenkins Plugin How to get Job information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115618/jenkins-plugin-how-to-get-job-information)

Comment: Thanks. then I'm not giving it the correct BUILD_JOB_NAME