# Jenkins plugin - how to get currently executing job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am building a jenkins pipeline plugin (methods to be invoked from a pipeline) and need to get retrieve information about the currently running job, which invoked my methods.

There are a couple of questions I found talking about it, for example here - [Jenkins Plugin How to get Job information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115618/jenkins-plugin-how-to-get-job-information).

Yet I can't figure out how to use this information. I do have access to the Jenkins instance, but don't have any info about the current project, job, build, etc.  How can I get hold of that info?

Note, this is a pipeline steps plugin, there is no `perform` method in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after search, I finally found the answer in the most obvious of all places - [documentation for writing pipeline steps plugins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-step-api-plugin) and the corresponding [API documentation](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-step-api/).

The way to do it is from the `Execution` class.  Inside it, just call `getContext()`, which returns `StepContext`, which then has `.get` method to get the rest of the things you need:

```
public class MyExecution extends SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution<ReturnType> {
    ...

    @Override
    protected ReturnType run() throws Exception {
        try {
            StepContext context = getContex();

            // get currently used workspace path
            FilePath path = context.get(FilePath.class);

            //get current run
            Run run = context.get(Run.class);

            // ... and so on ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, this post is interesting, but I do not get how you use this code. To get an instance of MyExecution you need to provide a context to it's constructor, how to you get it ? Secondly, the class is supposed to return a ReturnType, what is it exactly ?